# Google satellite basemap license

Tags: google-maps-api, google, machine-learning

Where (if anywhere) can we buy a license to use Google satellite basemap as input to machine learning algorithms?

Comment: Depending if your a business, non-profit or other etc. https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/gmp-billing

Comment: Thanks @Mapperz, they give an overview of cost for using Maps, Routes and Places. The closest match is perhaps the Maps Static API but I couldn't find anything about machine learning in their terms of service. https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/

Comment: update. I reached out on their contact form...